# Explicit binding to an object without using the current DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datacontext

**Description:**

I have some View having its `DataContext` is already set to some List.

I also have in there a `ComboBox` that should trigger a Visibility event to a `StackPanel`. It is done through a property "SelectedVisibility" that is implementing a `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

**Issue:**

The property "SelectedVisibility" isn't part of the `DataContext` but in a `ViewModel` class and I cannot find any way to explicitely bind my ViewModel to reach that property.

**Question:**

*Would you know how I could explicitely define my VM to be the DataContext of the SelectedValue binding in my ComboBox?*

**Code details:**

View XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource VisibilityEnum}}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedVisibility}"/>

<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding Path=SelectedVisibility,Converter={StaticResource SelectedValueToVisible}}">
```

View Code behind:

```
public Counterparties_UserInputs()
{
    // Cannot bind this as already bound
    // this.DataContext = _VM;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

View Model:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public string SelectedVisibility
{
    get 
    {
        return _selectedVisibility; 
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedVisibility= value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedVisibility"));
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new dependancy property to your view, bind your view model to this property and then use this property as DataContext for your StackPanel and ComboBox. For example ("this" is the name of your view, "AdditionalContext" is the dependancy property you declare to store your viewmodel):

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding AdditionalContext, ElementName=this}" Visibility="{Binding Path=SelectedVisibility, Converter={StaticResource SelectedValueToVisible}}"/>
```

However you should not do it, since it is a violation of MVVM pattern. The whole point of viewmodel is that you use it as DataContext for your view. The correct approach to your issue is to move List declaration to your viewmodel.

Comment: Thank you! And sorry for the late answer.
It is what I was looking for. I had done this design as I wanted to use my embeded user controls (V & VM) in other places of the code, but I think you're right so I've simplified to have only: 2 embeded user control (V only) & 1 main view (V & VM). Cheers!